# Can I integrate more than one Active Directory in Sitecore's Security?

Tags: active-directory, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Our Sitecore 7.2 instance uses the Active Directory Module to facilitate user management. We are about to give access to another office to our site, which uses a different instance of Active Directory.

Can I add more than one Active Directory to our instance? Do I just have to add another entry under  in the Web.config, or it is more tricky than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to add more AD to your Sitecore application.

Here is [Active Directory Module 1.2 for CMS 7.2 - 8.0 Administrator's Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/12/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc72-80-a4.pdf).

Check the **2.1.3 Modifying the Config Files** section. It says:

> You can define a number of connection strings  in the  `<connectionStrings>`element.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out!